# The smallest number which is divisible by first $10$ natural number

Tags: number-theory

The smallest number which is divisible by first $10$ natural numbers is $2520$, but why $0$ is not the smallest divisible number?

Answer (score 5):

There is no "smallest number", as $-2520$, and any multiple of that also works.

There is, however, a smallest *positive* number, and that is indeed $2520$. We specify "positive" instead of "non-negative", because in most cases where divisibility is concerned, $0$ is an uninteresting trivial case, and we want to look at all the *other* cases.